# Passing quotes to an onclick event within an html element within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This seems to be *one* step more complicated than similar posts I've seen:
I created the following line within a js function:

`content.push("<input type='button' value='Use This Location' onclick='alert(" + result.location.y + "," + result.location.x + ")'/>");`

The result is a button with the following:
`onclick="alert(40.7445068,-73.9834671)"`

but I want the result to be:
`onclick="alert('40.7445068,-73.9834671')"`

or.. you know.. just.. however it would take to make the alert show the text, not just the first number.

How can I reformat the quotes within the original block to make that happen?

Comment: You can use escaped double quotes `\"` however, in the long run you should create a DOM element and directly attach the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
content.push("<input type='button' value='Use This Location' onclick='alert(\"" +
result.location.y + ',' + result.location.x + "\")'/>");
```

EDIT: Fixed up the code some.

Comment: The argument that is passed to `alert` is still not a string.

Comment: That will create broken HTML now: `onclick="alert(" ...`. Use single quotes and escape them. *edit*: this works too :)

Comment: Just needed to do some cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add escaped single quotes (e.g. \')

so change

```
onclick='alert(" + result.location.y + "," + result.location.x + ")'
```

to

```
onclick='alert(\'" + result.location.y + "," + result.location.x + "\')'
```

edit: formatting issues

Comment: HTML does not understand such escape sequences: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KyTYw/. If you want the same quotation mark inside an attribute that you use to delimit its value, then you need to use the corresponding HTML entity: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KyTYw/1/

Comment: Hmmm, you could try replaceing the escapes with &#34; then.

Comment: So you are saying that the string is `" ... onclick='alert(\'" + ... + "\')' ... "`? Then this would result in `onclick='alert('...')'` which is broken HTML. That's one of the reason why one should not create (more complex) HTML strings in JavaScript ;) It just gets messy...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much folks!  Your input (no put intended) led to a workable solution:
`content.push('<input type="button" value="Use This Location" onclick="alert(&#39;'+ result.location.y + "," + result.location.x + '&#39;)" />');`

Since it's Javascript within HTML within Javascript, I passed the push method as single quotes instead of the original double ones, then I was able to make the html element double quotes and the `onclick` single.  Then I had to use `&#39;` instead of `&#34` so I could get a special single quote inserted within the HTML.

Again, thanks very much. All the comments were key in solving / I am grateful!

Comment: Answered by the OP in an edit. [Moved to this answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)