# How to handle click event on dynamically rendered html data?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am rendering html data using `innerHrml` in my div. Now i want to handle the click events on `<a>` tags on the html data. How can i do that?

Comment: I just posted on similar question.  To add onclick using innerhtml. over here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759830/how-to-pass-javascript-arguments-using-inner-html/61760156#61760156

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use event.target to target the element which is clicked. You will need to bind the function call to an element that already exists in the DOM. E.g.

```js
document.querySelector(".myDiv").addEventListener("click", e => console.log(event.target));
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"> <!-- existing element //-->
  <a href="#">Dynamically generated element</a>
</div>
```

This is called "event bubbling" You can learn more about it: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are normally handling click events by using the `onclick` attribute of the HTML `<a>` tag. The other method is to just use `document.getElementById("theId")` and the `addEventListener` method.

```js
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var dynamicDiv = document.getElementById("dynamicDiv");

start.addEventListener("click", function(){
  dynamicDiv.innerHTML = '<a id="new">Test this a tag by clicking it.</a>';
  
  var newTag = document.getElementById("new");
  newTag.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("The <a> tag was clicked.");
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="start">Click to dynamically display data</button>
<div id="dynamicDiv"></div>
```